# Unable to upload a file in Android and there's no details of an error

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to upload a file in Android/Kotlin:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //...........

    UploadFilesTask().execute(1)

}

//.......

private class UploadFilesTask : AsyncTask<Int, Int, Int>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Int?): Int? {
      val MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/jpg")
      val client = OkHttpClient()
      val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
          .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
          .addFormDataPart("title", "test123")
          .addFormDataPart("file", "image-name-123.jpg", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG,
              File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/real-file-name.jpg")))
          .build()

      val request = Request.Builder()
          .url("http://httpbin.org/post")
          .post(requestBody)
          .build()

      val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
      if (!response.isSuccessful) {
        throw IOException("Unexpected code " + response)
      } else {
        Log.d("test", "Done123")
        Log.d("test", response.body().string())
      }

      return 123
    }

    protected fun onProgressUpdate(vararg progress: Int) {
    }

    protected override fun onPostExecute(result: Int?) {
    }
  }
```

The only error message I can see when I run it is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
```

How can I fix it?

The permissions are set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and the dependency:

```
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1"
```

Comment: Maybe, you need to add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: @Majestic, ты чё? Голова. При чём тут write?

Comment: Don't use `/storage/emulated/0`, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman, no need.

Comment: Yes, there is a need, unless you are only targeting one device where you can ensure that path will always be there.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman, I am.

Comment: It's still bad practice.If you have a choice between writing the correct code, and incorrect code, and it's the same number of characters ... seems like a no brainer to me.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman, being a smart-ass is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it works as expected. The only difference with mine is that I used a real device, so the path to my file is `/storage/sdcard0/Download/real-file-name.jpg`. I recommend you to check the the file exists in your emulator storage:

`adb shell ls /storage/emulated/0/Download/real-file-name.jpg`

The output should be something like this:

`-rw-rw-r-- root     sdcard_rw    21577 2016-01-26 16:16 real-file-name.jpg`

This is an output example of your code

```
01-26 18:00:52.877 29568-29644/com.omainegra.sof D/test: Done123
01-26 18:00:54.383 29568-29644/com.omainegra.sof D/test: {
                                                         "args": {}, 
                                                         "data": "", 
                                                         "files": {
                                                             "file": "data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...
```

> Recomendation

A better (and reactive approach) could be done easily with `RxAndroid`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val observable = Observable.create<String> { observer ->
        try {
            if (!observer.isUnsubscribed) {
                val MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/jpg")
                val client = OkHttpClient()
                val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("title", "test123")
                        .addFormDataPart("file", "image-name-123.jpg", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG,
                                File("/storage/sdcard0/Download/real-file-name.jpg")))
                        .build()

                val request = Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://httpbin.org/post")
                        .post(requestBody)
                        .build()

                val response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                if (!response.isSuccessful)
                    throw IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                observer.onNext(response.body().string())
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            observer.onError(e);
        }
    }

    lateinit var subscription: Subscription

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        subscription = observable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ response ->
                    Log.d("test", "Done123")
                    Log.d("test", response)
                }, { error ->
                    Log.e("test", "onError", error)
                })
    }

    override fun onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy()
        subscription.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

Add dependencies to your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Or, you could just code one of the very most basic idioms ever using the classes provided in the SDK and not rely on the flavor of the week library / pattern.

Comment: why do I see the path "/storage/emulated/0/Download" in Android FileManager, whereas adb says the path doesn't exist and the correct one is "/storage/sdcard0/Download"?

Comment: I think you replied to the wrong post. Anyway, the reason Android provides `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is because there's no guarantee what that path will be. It'd device dependent.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman, once again: I see the different paths of the same smartphone.

Comment: it's a linux thing. one is following a symlink, the other is following the real path.